# What type of spider is this please?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Can anyone identify this spider please. Found in Herefordshire UK[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Identifications questions should include: 1) one or more clear closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible); 2) **habitat** information; 3) an estimate of the **size** of the organism; and 4) any behaviors that you observed. Please [edit] your post to include all this essential information. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like a young Steatoda of some sort, but that's really just a guess based on the shape and posture of the brown banded legs and the shape and relative sizes of the cephalothorax and abdomen.  The photo is good, but it would help to have some sort of size comparison like a coin, plus perhaps a bit more flash to expose any patterns on the top surface of the body.